# building an array from several ranges

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to build an array out of several ranges.  The following works:

```
array_of_ranges = (70..89).to_a + (184..193).to_a + (224..233).to_a + (296..304).to_a + (336..345).to_a
 => [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345]
```

and it's certainly much nicer than typing in a bunch of numbers - but I suspect there's a nicer, cleaner way to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the splat operator to do this quite cleanly:

```
[*70..89, *184..193, *224..233, *296..304, *336..345]
```

Result:

```
[70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def arrays_from *ranges
  ranges.map do |r|
    r.to_a
  end.flatten
end
```

or

```
def arrays_from *ranges
  ranges.map( &:to_a ).flatten
end

arrays_from 70..89, 184..193, 224..233
=> [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233]
```

Comment: That's definitely the right approach if you want to do it programmatically (e.g. you have an array of ranges stored in a variable already and you want to convert them into a single, continuous array). You could make it much shorter though: `ranges.flat_map(&:to_a)`

Comment: OK. I didn't know about `flat_map`. Thanks.